# I can't seem to get a way to get radio button group click events on jQuery ContextMenu by swisnl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a ContextMenu library that offers not only simple context menu but also inputs such as radio buttons, input texts, textareas, etc.

Thing is, after doing a little test example, i wasn't able to add a click event on the radio button group, it's weird because it looks like the click event is working for other inputs, even "keyup" events, but for radio buttons isn't.

This is the library and the example on this link contains radio buttons:

https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/input.html

Here's my little example:

```
items: {
            "settings": {
                "name": "Settings",
                "items" : {
                    "auto" : {
                        "name" : "Auto",
                        "type" : "radio",
                        "radio" : "radioGroup",
                        "value" : "auto"
                    },
                    "on" : {
                        "name" : "On",
                        "type" : "radio",
                        "radio" : "radioGroup",
                        "value" : "on"
                    },
                    "off" : {
                        "name" : "Off",
                        "type" : "radio",
                        "radio" : "radioGroup",
                        "value" : "off"
                    }
                },
                "events" : {
                    "click" : function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                }
            },
```

I tried other events, like "change", or instead of "events" adding a `"callback" : function()` too... but didn't work. Seems that it's missing.
I would like to be able to do something whenever that setting is modified.

Thanks.

Comment: That is global context menu events you try to assign, for single items you should define callbacks, as you can see in [this docs](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/callback.html).

Comment: yes, i tried that too, but didn't work, maybe i'm placing it in the wrong place?

Comment: What you showed above is wrong place for sure.

Comment: @skobaljic i tried putting it after the "off" object, and didn't work either.

Comment: Callback should be **inside** individual item, as I can see on docs page above. Also you can set the global callback... please refer to code on that page. Look at comment [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7679x0q/).

Comment: Yes, i understand but i tried putting a callback on every different structure level and seemed to be not working. Thanks for trying to help tho :)

Comment: Mate, there are no problems with the plugin, just start and expand their example. I made [a Fiddle for you here](https://jsfiddle.net/6wfuecox/). Just open console and look: all global click events are fired, also item specific event overrides global, as we can see for clicking Edit. Your settings object above is not correct, please copy paste the code and start from that.

Comment: @skobaljic Didn't you read the original post? nobody is talking about those simple items.... i'm talking about customized items like radio button groups... tested it many many ways, believe me... there was no way i could get the click event callback but using the on change as gaemaf suggested.

Comment: There is a way, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to bind events to `document`. As you could see on the [same demo page](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/input.html), the way to bind events to custom inputs is as follows:

```js
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "global: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
        "auto": {
            "name": "Enabled",
            "type": "checkbox",
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    console.log('Clicked checkbox');
                }
            }
        },
        "on1": {
            "name": "On",
            "type": "radio",
            "radio": "radioGroup",
            "value": "on",
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    console.log('Clicked On');
                }
            }
        },
        "off1": {
            "name": "Off",
            "type": "radio",
            "radio": "radioGroup",
            "value": "off",
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    console.log('Clicked Off');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/theme.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/theme-fixes.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/github.min.css">
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
```

Also [on this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wfuecox/2/).

Just sometimes we cannot see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Ohhhh lol, how df?? i tried this before but didn't work... looks like you were right this whole time, apologies!

Comment: Really no need to apology, could be you had some typo or your settings object was wrongly formatted (for Notepad++ you have a nice plugin called JSON Viewer, which can quickly format JSON object, as well as Javascript objects - it is very helpful). Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution according to the documentation ([jQuery contextMenu Events](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/events.html)) is:

```js
$(function () {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    items: {
      "Settings": {
        name: "Settings"
      },
      "auto": {
        "name": "Auto",
        "type": "radio",
        "radio": "radioGroup",
        "value": "auto"
      },
      "on": {
        "name": "On",
        "type": "radio",
        "radio": "radioGroup",
        "value": "on"
      },
      "off": {
        "name": "Off",
        "type": "radio",
        "radio": "radioGroup",
        "value": "off"
      }
    }
  });
  $(document).on("change", ".context-menu-item", function (e) {
    alert("Item Clicked: " + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/theme.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/css/theme-fixes.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/github.min.css">
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
```

Comment: Nice! it worked. Didn't want to use something that was outside the library structure but it's okay, looks like i have no other way to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: Nonsense, if they did it and created the example, than it has to work. You should not do it this way. Copy-paste their example and start from that point.